# partial view with tiny MCE editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

hello i am using bootstrap tabs and adding tabs dynamically like

$('.tab-content').append($(''));

then loading partial view with  data in new tab with ajax

```
$("#tab" + tabID).html('<div style="border-top:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09)">' + data + '</div>');
```

i am initializing tyni mce inside partialview

```
var xstring = "#txttab" + @Model.DOCUMENT_ID


tinymce.init({
    selector: xstring,
    height: 350,
    menubar: true,
    readonly: 1,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
      'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
      'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image'

});
```

everything works but when second tyni mce added to page it added to first tab tyni mce body

Comment: Scripts should not be in partials. Initialize your plugin in the ajax success callback after you have loaded the partial.

Comment: $(function () {
                                $('<script>')
                                  .attr('type', 'text/javascript')
                                  .text('tinymce.init({selector: "#txttab' + docID + '", height: 350,menubar: true, readonly: 1});').appendTo($("#tab" + tabID));
                            })
loaded in ajax succes; but problem steel exists. new tyni mce not loads in new tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added tinymce.remove(id);  id is textarea-s id.